# AWS Pinpoint does not work with Android devices

Tags: android, aws-mobilehub, aws-pinpoint

I created a MobileHub Project, I used exactly the same API Key and SenderId I use in Mixpanel. I then try to send a push notification using Pinpoint and it does not work. By the way I am able to send messages to IOS devices though. I also tested the same Android device with Google Firebase and Mixpanel and they both are working. It is only with AWS Pinpoint that it is not. Any Ideas why?

Comment: Take a look at this issue on Github: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2541#issuecomment-483171431